# Passing function with parameters as parameter of another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

I would like to pass a function with parameters to another function and have it run on an event, like this:

```
var main_object = function () {
    this.main_function = function (function) {
        document.addEventListener('click',function);
    }
    this.passed_function = function (variable) {
        alert(variable);
    }
}



var main_object = new main_object();
main_object.main_function(main_object.passed_function(3));
```

Comment: You should replace the parameter called "function" of main_function with something else. "function" is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right,

```
main_object.main_function(function() { main_object.passed_function(3) });
```

Comment: This is also a helpful answer. I'm going to try it out. I'm guessing this is how the EventListener function works.

Answer (score 2):

In modern JavaScript engines, you can [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function:

```
mainObject.main_function(main_object.passed_function.bind(main_object, 3));
```

The first argument to `bind` will be `this` when the function executes and any remaining arguments to `bind` will be leading arguments in the call to the function.

Comment: For compatibility, this link has some provided compatibility code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind I'm going to try this out to make sure I understand it correctly.

Comment: @JVE999 - yes, thanks for pointing out the compatibility code. That's the link I have in my answer.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I didn't notice it was a link, the color is similar to the regular text color on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

For what you're talking about, you could just use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). In your case, you would do:

```
main_object.main_function(main_object.passed_function.bind( main_object, 3 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mainfunc(func) {
    alert(func);
}

function callBackFn(a) {
    alert(a);
}
```

```
mainfunc("arg1", callBackFn("javaScritFnParameter"));  //call this in load
```

For sure it works no need to worry...  but callbackFn will execute first and next only "arg1" will execute.

Comment: Wow, that's super interesting. I'm not exactly sure how that works. For anyone who's wondering, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4hb8/)